# Conditional collapse of matrix rows with custom function

Tags: r, matrix

I want to collapse rows in a matrix so that no value of a particular column ever falls below 20. And I want to apply a custom function to the rows to collapse/sum them...

Here is an example matrix:

```
d <- matrix(data = c(0,105,1,21,2,11,4,5,5,15,7,21,9,1), 
   ncol = 2, 
   byrow = TRUE
)

colnames(d) <- c('val','freq')
```

Looking like this:

```
d
     val freq
[1,]   0  105
[2,]   1   21
[3,]   2   11
[4,]   4    5
[5,]   5   15
[6,]   7   21
[7,]   9    1
```

The column where the cells must be 20 or above is "freq". So row 1 and 2 are fine, but I need to collapse row 3:5. And I want to replace row 3:5 with the single row from this function:

```
library(reshape)

replacement <- function(x){

  mat <- d[x, ]
  mat.res <- untable(mat[ ,c(1, 2)], 
    num = mat[ ,2]
  )

  res <- c(mean(mat.res[ ,1]), length(mat.res[ ,1]))
  return(res)
}
```

The function call:

```
replacement(3:5)
[1]  3.774194 31.000000
```

Going through the matrix; row 6 is fine, but since row 7 would be left with `freq=1` this row needs to be collapsed with row 6. The function call again:

```
replacement(6:7)
[1]  7.090909 22.000000
```

The resulting matrix should be:

```
       val freq
[1,]   0   105
[2,]   1   21
[3,]   3.774194 31.000000
[4,]   7.090909 22.000000
```

The final row numbering is not important.

I have a feeling that the window functions of `dplyr` might hold the solution, but I need help understanding exactly how. It does not have to be `dplyr`. I take whatever works ;-)

Comment: As you have a matrix for using `dplyr` you may have to convert to `data.frame`  Also, it is not clear why you are taking row 6 as it is > 20

Comment: Just a quick question, you said that the row numbering is not important, but the original sorting is ? Because if not, you could have directly called `replacement(c(3:5,7))` ?

Comment: The original matrix is sorted on the column `val`. And the collapsed cells need to be adjacent ones in respect of the `val` column. So 'Yes', the original sorting is important.

Comment: @akrun, I need to collapse row 6 and 7 because if not, row 7 is left with `freq=1`. This is one of the issues I have when looping. If the last cells of `freq`does not sum to at leat 20, I need to somehow back up and redo the last collapse.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this is not very elegant, but it works...

```
rows <- dim(d)[1]
tmp <- NULL
inc <- 1
tmpSum <- 0

for(i in 1:rows){

    if(d[i, 2] > 19){
      tmp <- rbind(tmp, c(d[i, ], inc))
      inc <- inc + 1
      tmpSum <- 0

  } else {
    tmp <- rbind(tmp, c(d[i, ], inc))
    tmpSum <- d[i,2] + tmpSum 

    if(tmpSum > 19){
      inc <- inc + 1
    }
  }
}

if(sum(tmp[tmp[ ,3] == max(tmp[ ,3]), 2]) < 19){
  tmp[tmp[ ,3] == max(tmp[ ,3]), 3] <- tmp[tmp[ ,3] == max(tmp[ ,3]), 3]-1 
}

res <- NULL

for(i in 1:max(tmp[ ,3])){
  val <- mean(rep(tmp[tmp[ ,3] == i, 1], tmp[tmp[ ,3] == i, 2]))
  freq <- length(rep(tmp[tmp[ ,3] == i, 1], tmp[tmp[ ,3] == i, 2]))
  res <- rbind(res, c(val, freq))
}

res
```